# Alternative to libraries_get_path() to get a JavaScript file path

Tags: javascript

I was crafting the following code in order to alter the path to a JavaScript file.

```
function MY_MODULE_js_alter(&$javascript) {
      $sm_path = libraries_get_path('soundmanager2'). '/script/soundmanager2.js';
      $javascript['sites/all/libraries/soundmanager2/script/soundmanager2-nodebug-jsmin.js']['data'] = $sm_path;
      }
```

It works fine, but the only thing that bothers me is that `libraries_get_path()` is provided by the Libraries API module. Is there an internal Drupal 7 function to act the same way?

Answer (score 4):

You can get the same data using [`drupal_get_library()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_get_library/7), but it's not in a friendly format so you'll have to dig into the array yourself. For example, the following code will get the same path as your current code but in a much less less satisfying manner (in my opinion anyway):

```
$lib = drupal_get_library('soundmanager2', 'soundmanager2_debug');
$sm_path = array_shift(array_keys($lib['js']));
```

As I understand it this is actually the *reason* there's a need for the Libraries API to exist...so this sort of thing can be managed in a structured manner.

Comment: Definitely, this useful libraries_get_path() function should be included in Drupal core, what do you think?

Comment: Yes it would definitely be helpful, in fact there's an [open issue](http://drupal.org/node/667058) on drupal.org requesting the addition of the Libraries API in it's entirety to core for Drupal 8. Unfortunately it won't be back-ported to D7 core from what I can tell.

Comment: @onirio It will not back-ported because it is too late for adding new modules to Drupal 7 core.

Answer (score 2):

[drupal_get_library()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_get_library/7) returns a library that is between those libraries a module defines in its [hook_library()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_library/7) implementation. If there isn't a module that defines that JavaScript library with `hook_library()`, then `drupal_get_library()` is not a valid alternative to `libraries_get_path()`.

If you just want to look for a library, without requiring the Libraries module as dependency for your module, you can use [libraries_get_path()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!libraries!libraries.module/function/libraries_get_path/7), and [libraries_get_libraries()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!libraries!libraries.module/function/libraries_get_libraries/7) code to write your own function.
I would rather make a module dependent from the Libraries module for the simple fact you don't need to maintain that code. It is up to you to decide if creating a dependency from the Libraries module is worth being done, in your case.

The alternative to make the Library module a dependency for your module, and copying the code used from the Libraries module is to hardcode the location where your module is looking for the JavaScript library. Considering that users are already used to the Libraries module, and considering that more than one module could use the same JavaScript library your code is using, I think the Libraries module is still the valid solution to your case.